# Can iCal schedule an event for the first weekday after BYMONTHDAY if BYMONTHDAY is a weekend?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

If I have a recurring event on a given day of the month (i.e. the 15th) and that day falls on a Saturday or a Sunday, is it possible for iCal to instead schedule the event to occur on the next available week day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you cannot set exception but you can use a combination of byday and bymonthday:
something like will give you the monday after a week-end which had either on saturday or sunday a 15th.

RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO;BYMONTHDAY=16,17

By combining with another event:
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=15

you'll be there

Comment: Hi. Do you think you could have a look at my similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980216/how-to-create-an-icalender-event-that-repeats-very-irregulary ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Using the `BYSETPOS=1` rule part, you can accomplish this in a single event:

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=15,16,17;BYSETPOS=1
```

This tells iCal to repeat the event monthly; to repeat it only Monday-Friday; to repeat it only on the 15th-17th; and to repeat it only on the first day (per month) that matches the previous rule parts.

`BYSETPOS` just tells iCal to choose the Nth occurrence of the set of occurrences matched by the other rule parts. It can be set to a comma separated list of values from 1 to 366 or -366 to -1.

For example, modifying the above rule to have `BYMONTHDAY=15,16,17,29,29,30,31` and `BYSETPOS=1,-1` will cause the event to repeat on the first weekday on or after the 15th, and the last weekday in the month.

Source: [RFC 2445](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt)

Comment: Hi. Do you think you could have a look at my similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73980216/how-to-create-an-icalender-event-that-repeats-very-irregulary ? Thank you.