# iCal Recurring monthly event on the closest weekday possible?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I would like to create a recurring event on the 24th of every month and if the day falls on a weekend, schedule it for the **closest weekday**. If the day falls on a Saturday, I would like to schedule it for the previous weekday (Friday). If the day falls on a Sunday, I would like to schedule it for the next weekday (Monday). Is this something that is possible to do with iCal RRULE?

I have already seen a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101167/can-ical-schedule-an-event-for-the-first-weekday-after-bymonthday-if-bymonthday), but that was for always the next weekday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a recurring event based on your requirements using this combined iCAL RRULE

```
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=23,24;BYSETPOS=-1
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=24,25;BYSETPOS=1
```

RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=23,24;BYSETPOS=-1

- By setting BYSETPOS to -1, this rule will choose the last occurrence within the set occurrences that matched the rule.

> If both 23 and 24 falls on weekdays, it will choose the last occurrence which is the 24th day
>
> If 24 falls on a Saturday, only one occurrence will be matched based on the rule, Hence it will choose the 23rd day on Friday
>
> If both 23 and 24 fall on weekends, no event will be created. This is why another rule is needed to resolve this issue.

RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYMONTHDAY=24,25;BYSETPOS=1

- By setting BYSETPOS to 1, this rule will choose the first occurrence within the set occurrences that matched the rule.

> If both 24 and 25 falls on weekdays, it will choose the first occurrence which is the 24th day
>
> If 24 falls on a Sunday, only one occurrence will be matched based on the rule, Hence it will choose the 25th day on Monday
>
> If both 24 and 25 fall on weekends, no event will be created based on this rule.

Comment: Thanks! This (having 2 RRULEs) does work when imported to Google Calendar. However, when importing to Apple Calendar, it only seems to support the first rule. Any ideas on if Apple Calendar supports more than 1 RRULE in one event?

Comment: Glad to hear that, regarding your other concern, from the looks of it the limitation seems to be from Apple Calendar. The best option i could suggest is to ask this concern to Apple in this community https://apple.stackexchange.com/